# How do I remove keys from hash that have a bank value while skipping the first key

Tags: ruby

I'm trying to remove any keys in a hash that has a blank value besides the first key. I'm also trying to do this on one line.

Here is what I have which gives a whole bunch of syntax errors. I keep fiddling with it to try fix the syntax errors but nothing works. Where am I going wrong?

```
hash.each_with_index do { |(key, value), i| value.blank? && i != 0 ? key.delete :    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One liner:

```
hash.delete_if.with_index {|(k, v), i| v.nil? && i != 0 }
```

Comment: I now realise how much I was overcomplicating it.

Answer (score 0):

Using `select`:

```
h = { a: '', b: '', c: 1 }
puts h.select.with_index { |subh, i| !(subh[1].to_s.empty?) || i == 0 }
# => {:a=>'', :c=>1}
```

You should think carefully if you really want to rely on ordering when using a Hash though.

Comment: Sorry for not posting it but the hash will be like this `h = { a: "", b: "", c: "1" }` with strings as values. If I just replace `.nil` with `.blank` that should suffice?

Comment: @user3234020 I updated my answer to adequate your specs.